# Google Charts: chxl and bhg

Tags: charts, google-visualization

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhg&chd=t:3771.5,3220|5508.25,5366.75&
chs=400x200&chds=0,9000&chxt=x&chxr=0,0,9000&
chm=N*cUSD2s*,000000,0,-1,11|N*cUSD2s*,000000,1,-1,11&chco=4D89D9,C6D9FD
```

How to put label for each group?

`chxl=1:|Mean|Median` - should do something like this, but result is nothing

By groups I mean this numbers: 1 = { 3771.5, 5508.25 }, 2 = { 3220, 5366.75 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending this:

```
&chxt=x,y,r&chxl=2:|Mean|Median|
```

It might not be exactly what you want, but it works fine when I tried it.

Comment: you solved it, I needed - "&chxt=x,y&chxl=1:|Mean|Median|", thanks